# Secure Menu Items Based on User

Tags: winforms, security, menuitem

On this winform application I am writing, I want to secure one menu item from most users. It runs a month-end and cannot be easily backed out if accidentally run. The menu option opens up a window to prompt the user for some information before processing. I don't care where exactly I do the check, but I want to be sure only certain users can run this function.

A Google search (on my question title above) didn't turn up anything obvious. Can anyone point me in a direction to pick up who is signed into Windows and how to check if they are authorized?

Comment: How are you deciding 'authorized'? Based on an AD group? Based on a database call? Based on a deployment switch (e.g a special admin edition? All depends.

Comment: @Reddog To be determined... For now (for testing) it is hard-coded in. That is NOT the final solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20200804123454/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/Ramaraju/archive/2009/07/14/windows_authentication_in_winform_application.aspx) has some code for getting user details and checking them.

This code:

```
public string GetloggedinUserName()
{
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity currentUser =
                      System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    return currentUser.Name;
}
```

returns the current user name. You could use this to check against your list of authorised users.

More details on the `WindowsIdentity`class can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?view=net-7.0).

It has a [`Groups`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.groups?view=net-7.0) property which you could use to check for membership of a group rather than having to check individual users.

Comment: I'll have to talk to others in the department to see what method they prefer.